# Flutter web - ReordorableListView with + button on hover between fields

Tags: flutter, listview, dart, drag-and-drop, hover

I am working on a Flutter Web project, and we would like to have a [`ReordorableListView`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ReorderableListView-class.html) design. We also would like to have a *"+"* button between the cards of the list when the user hovers between 2 elements (to then add an element at the chosen position).

I tried to do it by including in the list a widget (which is transparent and becomes a *"+"* when hovered). But by doing this, this widget is also draggable by the user which I don't want.

Here is a simple example:

```dart
class Screen extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ReorderableListView(
      onReorder: (int oldIndex, int newIndex) {},
      children: [
        const Card(
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Text('Value 0'),
          ),
          key: Key('key0'),
        ),
        PlusButton(
          key: Key('plusButton'),
        ),
        const Card(
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Text('Value 1'),
          ),
          key: Key('key1'),
        ),
        const Card(
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Text('Value 2'),
          ),
          key: Key('key2'),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class PlusButton extends StatefulWidget {
  PlusButton({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _PlusButtonState createState() => _PlusButtonState();
}

class _PlusButtonState extends State<PlusButton> {
  bool isHovered = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MouseRegion(
      onEnter: (_) {
        print('enter');
        setState(() {
          isHovered = true;
        });
      },
      onExit: (_) {
        print('exit');
        setState(() {
          isHovered = false;
        });
      },
      child: Container(
        height: 20,
        width: 50,
        color: Colors.red, // Should be transparent, red to see it in the example
        child: isHovered
            ? IconButton(
                iconSize: 10,
                icon: const Icon(Icons.add),
                onPressed: () {},
              )
            : null,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The list :

[image]

When the button is hovered:

[image]

As you can see, the button is also draggable:

[image]

How can I display a *"+"* button between 2 elements when the user hovers there ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find any proper way to do what I wanted to do. A workaround I found was to put a `GestureDetector` on the `Container` of the button with a non-null (but empty) `onLongPress` to block the drag of the widget.

Here is the updated code:

```dart
class Screen extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ReorderableListView(
      onReorder: (int oldIndex, int newIndex) {},
      children: [
        const Card(
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Text('Value 0'),
          ),
          key: Key('key0'),
        ),
        PlusButton(
          key: Key('plusButton'),
        ),
        const Card(
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Text('Value 1'),
          ),
          key: Key('key1'),
        ),
        const Card(
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Text('Value 2'),
          ),
          key: Key('key2'),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class PlusButton extends StatefulWidget {
  PlusButton({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _PlusButtonState createState() => _PlusButtonState();
}

class _PlusButtonState extends State<PlusButton> {
  bool isHovered = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onLongPress: () {}, // To prevent the drag
      child: MouseRegion(
        onEnter: (_) {
          print('enter');
          setState(() {
            isHovered = true;
          });
        },
        onExit: (_) {
          print('exit');
          setState(() {
            isHovered = false;
          });
        },
        child: Container(
          height: 20,
          width: 50,
          color: Colors.red, // Should be transparent, red to see it in the example
          child: isHovered
              ? IconButton(
                  iconSize: 10,
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.add),
                  onPressed: () {},
                )
              : null,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can look inside `ReorderableListView`, there is a `buildDefaultDragHandle` param in there. By setting it to false, the widget won't automatically make items draggable anymore, but it let you wrap your item with the `ReorderableDragStartListener` or `ReorderableDelayedDragStartListener`(needs long press to trigger dragging).

Off-topic: I have a similar feature-request too, but it's to make the "plus button" hover on top of the ListView, not in between the items.

Flutter is not good at creating unordinary layout by it's raw abilities, tried to use a SizedBox.shrink combined with OverflowBox, it graphically works but the HitTest won't work because the overflow part won't count.